# Parent Control containing child control which is of same type as parent control

Tags: asp.net, nested, user-controls

I need to create a asp.net form which needs to show a list of folders where each folder may further contain other folder and file.  Like window folder view it can be nested to n-level. I can't use tree view control as some edting and formatting requirement can't be met. The datastructure i am using is not folder view but almost same as folderview.

I first tried to create a usercontrol, say **FolderList**,showing list of folders. It contains listview where each item of the listview shows the name of the folder and also contains an instace another UserControl, say **folderDetail**. 
   **folderDetail** contains an instance of Usercontrol **FolderList** and a listview showing files in those folders. But it failed with the exception "Circular file references are not allowed".

Next i am thinking if i can add control dynamically and get Ajax working on it someway. But that gonna take some effort.

Please suggest me a proper solution so that such nested struture can be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can add controls dynamically, also without ajax. In the databound event of the list view load and add the user control you need, dynamically with the `LoadControl` function.